# How to get value of view from the click of other view in the same view parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am adding a layout on a `Button` click that layout contains a `TextView` and the 2 `Spinners` name *spGrades* and *spMarks*.

User can add multiple layout.  So all I want is to get the value of `Spinner`s on the `TextView` click . well I am getting of values of `Spinner` but I am facing following problems.

1. In Case1: Suppose there is just one layout added by the user let say
   *Student1MarksLayout* then on the click of the `TextView` I am getting
   the values of `Spinners`.
2. In Case 2: Suppose now user has added and other layout let say
   Student2MarksLayout with same 2 spinners and a `TextView` . Now in
   this case on the click listener of `TextView` I am getting the value
   of spinners which are currently added.  even though i click on the
   `TextView` of the *Student1MarksLayout*. It brings the values of
   *Student2MarksLayout* values.

**Question:**

> So in fact I want to get the values of spinners differently from the
>   same view group in which the `TextView` click has been originated by the
>   user.

Please help me and any suggestion about this on how to maintain this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the function that creates the layout, add to final variables that hold the 2 Spinners. Then create the onClick function, and reference these 2 final variables. I have written a quick example (in a bit of shorthand)

```
void createLayout()
{
    View v = inflate....
    final Spinner a  = v.findViewById...
    final Spinner b  = v.findViewById...
    TextView t  = v.findById...
    t.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     int val = a.get....
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can yew please elaborate what are you saying ?

Comment: I have added a quick example to my answer.